# In CHAID, shouldn't we merge categories when p<alpha rather than p>alpha?

Tags: data-mining, algorithms, cart

In CHAID, the categories are merged when P>alpha in the first step.

BUT

Since CHAID uses Chi-square statisitic, if p-value < alpha, we reject the null ( Independence), hence, meaning the categories are not independent, thus Merge.But this line of thought is not the case reading the algorithm steps, which says merge when p > alpha (i.e. Merge when you fail to reject that they are independent?) It seems like it is just the opposite.

So, should we merge when the categories are dependent or independent? and why?

What am i missing?

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing things. `Independence` is between the dependent variable and the predictor variable, not between categories of the latter, which are to merge or not to merge.

Comment: Yes, I did confuse this; thanks for pointing this out. But the CHAID still does not make sense completely? So with the chi-sq test, we are saying that if result is not significant, we fail to see any relationship betn the dep and indep var (that is, they are indep), so the indep var should be merged?

Comment: CHAID screens various ways to merge categories in the predictor to select the the best merge which gives the greatest or the most significant association between it and the dependent var.